# Blazor button click handler not retaining parameter value

Tags: onclick, blazor

I am creating a table in a for-loop and adding a button in each cell with a click handler method. I am passing the cell value as a parameter to the click handler method. The cell value is also generated using the same for loop. When the button is clicked, it updates the contents of a div using the passed down parameter value. I was expecting it to display the value for which the button was clicked. But it always shows the value on which the for-loop ended. It seems, the click handler method is not holding on to the value that was passed to it during the button creation. Following is the code from the razor page and the code behind: The project can be downloaded from [this location](https://github.com/aamirghanchi/GridClick)

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<div>Number Clicked is  @NumberClicked</div>
<table>
    @for(int i=0; i< 6; i++){
        <tr><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-link" @onclick="()=> {ButtonClicked(i);}">@i</button></td></tr>
    }
</table>

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace GridClick.Pages
{
    public partial class Index : ComponentBase
    {
        public string NumberClicked { get; set; }

        public void ButtonClicked(int i)
        {
            NumberClicked = i.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incrementing the `i` after every iteration. This means that the `i` you are using is shared between all iterations and will have the latest updated value when you click on the button.
What you can do is create a temporary variable and copy the value to this variable and use it in your for loop.

```
@for(int i=0; i< 6; i++)
{
    int index = i;
    <tr>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-link" 
        @onclick="()=> {ButtonClicked(index);}">@index</button></td> 
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you. The code I posted was an oversimplified example of an actual set of data record being displayed in an html table. The hint you gave about using a temporary variable can be applied in my situation as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve your issue is to use `foreach` with `Enumerable.Range` because using `for` loop retains the last iteration value when rendered.

```html
<div>Number Clicked is @NumberClicked</div>

<table>
    @foreach (var index in Enumerable.Range(1, 6))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link"
                        @onclick="() => { ButtonClicked(index); }">
                    @index
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: @Aamir My pleasure. I was about to post the actual answer but klekmek was fast. Thanks for your appreciation.